# programmatically delete .git .idx .pack files

Tags: windows, git, file

ASP.NET C# app running on Windows Server 2008

I'm finding that Git .idx and .pack files to be especially resistant to programmatic deletion :

> C:\github\my-org\my-repo\.git\objects\pack\pack-905fbcfd5f24c5711de900f3946b4137d26df6d5.idx
>
> C:\github\my-org\my-repo\.git\objects\pack\pack-905fbcfd5f24c5711de900f3946b4137d26df6d5.pack

`git clone` operation creates files as read-only - but even once that bit switched-off, it remains problematic to delete :

```
var path = @"C:\github\my-org\my-repo\.git\objects\pack\pack-33ea2068b66028f98ac9deb55c3b5d1450d65dea.idx";

File.SetAttributes(path , FileAttributes.Normal);
File.Delete(path);
```

`File.Delete(path)` code throws exception :

> Access to the path 'pack-33ea2068b66028f98ac9deb55c3b5d1450d65dea.idx'
>   is denied.

Since the paths are not within my site dir, I'm wondering if the ASP.NET site AppPool worker-process identity needs to be explicitly assigned permissions to write/delete folders/files outside of its app domain ?

Note that on my Windows 7 local workstation, my nUnit test that invokes the delete dir operation runs green. In the debugger, I can prove that once the read-only attribute is removed from all files ( if present ), the Directory.Delete(path,true) operation does not throw.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "especially resistant"? They're just files. (Unless maybe some other process has that file open at the same time.)

Comment: the exception would seem to indicate presence of a lock but there is none -- this app is executing on a dedicated remote server and in fact same app creates the local repo

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner running on this server? Virus scanners can often cause this sort of behaviour if they are scanning the file at the time you try to delete it.

Answer (score 7):

Either a process is keeping an handle on that specific pack file ([process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can [check that for you](https://serverfault.com/a/1980/783))

Or there is a right access issue, as in [libgit2sharp/issues/769](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/769):

> > The message looks like the one you'd get when the reason is that you're trying to remove a read-only file, which Windows does not like, and the objects git's object database (of which that index file is one) are read-only.
>
> Removing readonly flag allows me to delete the whole directory.

Comment: error is occurring on remote server to which i have no direct access ( only via TeamCity ) but on my local workstation `File.SetAttributes(path , FileAttributes.Normal);` works nicely to remove read-only attribute so i would expect it to do in other environments

Comment: OK, that must be an access right issue on the server then.